# Add legend to scatter plot to differentiate colours, when there are multiple data types?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, scatter-plot

How do we add a scatter plot legend which signifies the different colors on python chart?

i.e. how do we turn chart 1 into chart 2

### Chart with data types has legend missing

[image]

### Chart without data types has legend

[image]

```
fig_1, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 10))
for marker, d in df2.groupby('Marker'):
    plt.scatter(x=d['Vol'], y=d['Expected Return'],alpha = 0.9, c=d['Correlation to 10y'],s=d["Size"], marker=marker\
               , cmap='viridis')
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.3, 0.5))
plt.title("Expected Return (Carry + Convexity) vs. Volatility")
```

where df2 is:

[image]

```
Rate    Vol Zscore  GammaPnLBps Carry   Carry/Vol   Expected Return Expected Sharpe Correl  Size    Correlation to 10y  Marker  Type
1Y  5.43    19.303584   0.024967    3.260498    -32.00  -1.657723   -28.739502  -1.488817   0.975701    975.701378  0.975701    .   Outright
7Y  4.79    50.635923   0.017388    17.093311   2.00    0.039498    19.093311   0.377070    0.997502    997.502246  0.997502    .   Outright
1s2s    0.35    0.350000    0.350000    0.350000    0.35    0.350000    0.350000    0.350000    0.350000    350.000000  0.350000    *   Curve
1s10s   0.65    0.650000    0.650000    0.650000    0.65    0.650000    0.650000    0.650000    0.650000    650.000000  0.650000    *   Curve
```

Comment: What did you mean by "chart with data types"? By data types are you saying the axis labels?
Please provide the code that introduces the error.